# Method called from setInterval, stops executing halfway through

Tags: javascript

My draw() function stops executing after calling this.circle(). If I call the draw() method directly, it works perfectly. However, if I use setInterval(this.draw, 1000), it seems to return right when calling this.circle(). circle() is never executed either. Am I misusing setInterval?

```
function Ball() {
   this.start = function() {
       return setInterval(this.draw, 1000);
   }
   this.circle = function() {
       console.log('1');
   }
   this.draw = function() {
       console.log('2');       

       this.circle();
       console.log('3');
}
```

this.circle() is never executed, and console.long('3') (or anything after it) is never reached.

The result is console.long('2') being repeatedly printed every 1 second

Comment: Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `setInterval`, `this` will refer to `window`. `window` doesn't have a function called `draw`, so it will throw an error and stop execution. To fix it, you need to bind the value of `this`.

```
return setInterval(this.draw.bind(this), 1000);
```

Comment: I was fiddling with this and I was getting an error this.circle() is not a function, it was executing this.draw() , but draw couldn't call circle. Your solution works but I don't see how exactly. JS is odd.

Comment: @MatthewPage You should study a bit of `this` in JavaScript. `this` refers to whatever is calling the function, when you use setInterval, your function will be called later on by `window`. Window here means global scope. Global scope doesn't have a function called `circle`. To fix it, you can use the function `bind` that is in the prototype of all functions. This function returns a new function, where `this` will always refer to the argument you pass to `bind`. So when you call `circle`, this will be the argument you sent on `bind`, that is, the original `this`

Comment: I think I get it, but the global scope doesn't have a function called `draw` either, so how come the error wasn't `this.draw()` is not a function?

Comment: https://codepen.io/matthewpageuk/pen/pGgZWq - console log shows circle error in function Ball.draw - how did the global scope know about the ball?

Comment: You are passing a function to the setInterval, its a function that exists at that context. But inside that function, `this` won't refer to the object.

Comment: Ok, I think I get what it's doing, but it seems very odd an object can loose awareness of itself. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Well, its not the object that lose awarenes of itself. Its the function =). Look up OO styles in JavaScript. If you did prototype methods, it would have worked

Answer (score 2):

“this” is no longer what you think it is, and you have lost context to it, it no longer represents Ball like you’d like it to.  You can bind your draw function like “this.draw.bind(this)” or you can capture “this” using a line like “const _this = this;” and then only reference “_this” in your functions to make sure you are always accessing the correct one.

Some reading on the closures

https://javascript.info/closure

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [@iagowp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3170151/iagowp) `this` will refer to the `window` when your method is called by `setInterval`. Instead, you can fix this by using an ES6 arrow function to call `this.draw()`. This way your `this` is referring to the `Ball` object rather than the function which called `this.draw()`.

See working example below:

```js
function Ball() {
  this.start = function() {
    return setInterval(_ => this.draw(), 1000);
  }
  this.circle = function() {
    console.log('1');
  }
  
  this.draw = function() {
    console.log('2');

    this.circle();
    console.log('3');
  }
}

let b = new Ball();
b.start();
```